# Access get_option within a class

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote my own Plugin and i want to access my plugin options in a Config class. Here is an example of my code.

```
class Config {
private $var = get_option('option');

public function getMyOption () {
  return $this->var;
}
}
```

But i get this error :

```
parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in
```

The Problem here ist how can i use the option values in a class?
Could somebody explain me, how i can access the get_option value in a class?

Comment: You will have to do it in the constructor or initialize it somewhere in a method. ["This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated."](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use function calls in property initializations, you can only initialize with literals. You have to do it in the class constructor.

```
class Config {
    private $var;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->var = get_option('option');
    }

    public function getMyOption() {
        return $this->var;
    }
}
```